# How to delete a div checking the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

I have an app that have some cards and I just added a button to reedem the card which would delete the card if clicked. I created a database table to save the information about the card and the customer id and date of redemption; I want the program to check if the user has already used that card (with the database information) then remove if forever.

I tried using jQuery '.remove()' but if you reload the webpage the card appears again.

1. Button - 2. AJAX call - 3. Database POST

```
                  <span class="buttonRedemp">
                    <button class="redddButt load-button2" data="Reedem Card">Reedem Card</button>
                  </span>

$(`#promotion-container .promo${i} .redddButt`).click(function(e){

        $('#deletePromo').on('click', function(){
            $(`#promotion-container .promo${i}`).remove();
        }) // this button is coming from a pop up

        $('#just-claimed-popup2').addClass('reveal');
        var theDiv = document.getElementById("card-just-claimed");
        var content = document.createTextNode(eventName);
        theDiv.appendChild(content);

        let dateReedem = moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY')

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/promotions_redemption',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                eventName : eventName,
                dateReedem : dateReedem,
            }
        });


    })

router.post('/promotions_redemption', function(req, res) {
  let customerID = req.user.customer_id
  let eventName = req.body.eventName
  let dateReedem = req.body.dateReedem

  // Inserts promotion card reedeem into rewards table
  db.any(`INSERT INTO promotions_redemption (customer_id, event_name, date_claimed) values ($1, $2, $3)RETURNING customer_id`,[customerID, eventName, dateReedem])
  .then(function() {
    return res.json({'eventName': eventName})
  })
  .catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err)
  })
})
```

Until now If you click the button I'm getting the information on the database, and deletes the card (with the '.remove()') but if you reload the page, the card appears again. I want to add some logic to check if the eventName and customer id already exist on the database then delete the card for that person.

Comment: How do you display the card from the database?

Comment: I don't exactly get your question. You said you already have code that deletes the div on a click. And now you want to code some logic that runs on each page-load and checks for some database-information and adjusts context depending on that... Then just code the logic. If you run into problems, we are always here to help :) Also, you might want to check JS-frameworks like "Vue", "Angular" and "React". They take a small amount of time to get into, but once you are into it, they are very easily doing what you seem to be doing here :)

Comment: It works but if you reload the app it will appear again, so I want it to check with the database to see if its already the information there, then remove it. And I know I love react but this was built on node.js

Comment: If it keeps appearing after you deleted it means that your databasequery does not work.

Comment: I don't want to delete from the database, I want it to submit the information to the database and then remove the div for that person. I already tried even making an Ajax call to get the info that I want to work with but the div keeps appearing after you reload the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should adjust the way in which the information of each of the cards is brought, validating that the cards that are being shown do not appear in the table promotions_redemption, but it is only a comment, you could add the query of how the list of cards